# Click the button to create a SELECT and an OPTION element

Tags: javascript, html

The example of code that I have posted is referenced from https://www.w3schools.com/ This particular code produces a select option after toggling a button. Currently the code produces a select dropdown with only one option but I would like multiply options. In particular, I have an array that I would like to fill as options in the select box. How could I add multiple options to the dropdown? Thanks!

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>Click the button to create a SELECT and an OPTION element.</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var selectElement = document.createElement("SELECT");
      selectElement.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
      document.body.appendChild(selectElement);

      var optionElement = document.createElement("option");
      optionElement.setAttribute("value", "volvocar");

      var textNode = document.createTextNode("Volvo");
      optionElement.appendChild(textNode);

      document.getElementById("mySelect").appendChild(optionsElement);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop and iterate your array and do the same thing your example is doing except inside the loop and create new option element for each item and append to the dropdown

Comment: I will never understand why w3schools, having improved greatly, still insists on using single letter variable names, with no shred of meaning

Comment: @Jamiec I used to do this, as a newcomer to JS, as I thought it was best to keep filesizes down (!)

Comment: @wiiiiilllllll and now you realise thats what minifaction/compression is for, right?

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, don't worry, I've seen the light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate your array of option values and append them to the drop down like so:

```
//Example array of values for adding to drop down
const myArray = [ "Dog", "Cat", "Bird" ];

//Iterate your array of values
for(let x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++){
    let z = document.createElement("option");
    z.setAttribute("value", myArray[x]); //Add value of the current item from array
    let t = document.createTextNode(myArray[x]); //Add text of the current item from array
    z.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("mySelect").appendChild(z);
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Being new in the world of javascript I highly appreciate the comments in the code, thanks!

Comment: @NicholasSpoutz You're welcome. If you are happy with my answer, you can show your appreciation with an upvote or marking it as the accepted answer. :)

Comment: I wish I could but since I'm a new user I get this popup when I try to upvote you, "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @NicholasSpoutz No problem. Thanks for the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The example is using single letter variable names, had they have used more meaningful ones (like `newOption` in place of `z`) you would probably have worked it out - just repeat that bit of code that generates just the new option, perhaps inside a loop.

```js
function createSelect() {
  var select = document.createElement("SELECT");
  select.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
  document.body.appendChild(select);

  var items = ["Foo","Bar","Zoo"];
  for(var i = 0;i<items.length;i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.setAttribute("value", item);
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(item);
    newOption.appendChild(textNode);
    select.appendChild(newOption);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to create a SELECT and an OPTION element.</p>

<button onclick="createSelect()">Try it</button>
```

Word of advice - use [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead of w3schools, better documentation and examples.

Comment: Advice taken. It seems to me W3 has been nice from an introduction standpoint but seems to struggle in terms of explanation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think this approach is slower than mine

Answer (score -1):

```
<p>Click the button to create a SELECT and an OPTION element.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var ele = document.createElement("SELECT");
        ele.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");  
        document.body.appendChild(ele);

        var values=["option0","option1","option2","option3"];
        // foreach the  values array 
        for(i in values){
            // i is  the index of values;
            // create option  item
            var item = document.createElement("option");
            item.setAttribute("value", values[i]);
            item.innerText=values[i]; 
            ele.appendChild(item); 
        } 

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Code without any explanation as to what you've done or why is of limited usefulness. Look at similar upvoted answers in tags you're interested in for the kind of answer expected.

Comment: I think it is so simple,so i didn't write  explanation.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer this approach, it's cleaner to me ^^

```js
function createSelect() {
  var select = document.createElement("select");
  document.body.appendChild(select);

  var items = ["pizza","margherita","buona"];
  
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = item;
    select.add(option);
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createSelect()">CREATE SELECT</button>
```

Comment: You could improve this by giving some explanation as to *why* you prefer this approach, and what it improves. Also, if you;re going for speed a `forEach` method call is many times slower than a vanilla `for` loop.